# Keep data consistency between redis and mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, redis

In my view to keep data consistency between redis and mysql result is always flush the redis key-value and reassign it with the newer sql result when the table had transaction before(write-update-delete) if dont have transaction then keep the redis key-value.

is that good way?any better solution for this?